# add values in a array list

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have the following ArrayList

```
ArrayList<double[]> db_results = new ArrayList<double[]>();
```

Which is populated by the following loop

```
double[] nums = new double[3];
for ( int i = 0 ; i <= 2; i++) {
    double val = Double.parseDouble(i);
    nums[i] = val;        
}
db_results.add(nums);
```

How can i add the values from the same position in each array to make another array??
So 1+1+1=3 would be position one of the new array 2+2+2=6 would be position two of the new array and 3+3+3=9 would be position three of the new array??

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for:

```
double[] newArray = new double[3];
for (double[] array : db_results) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        newArray[i] += array[i];
    }
}
```

It will work after `db_results` has been populated. You can also compute the sum array at the same time that `db_results` is being populated using slukian's method.

Answer (score 2):

A nested loop would do it.

I would encourage you to take the time to do a Java tutorial or read a textbook.  This is really basic stuff, and you'd do better learning the language properly than learning by trial and error interspersed with random SO questions.

---

By the way, this line from your code won't compile:

```
double val = Double.parseDouble(i);
```

The `i` variable is declared as an `int` and the `parseXxx` methods take a `String` argument.  To convert an `int` to `double`, just assign it:

```
double val = i;
```

Answer (score 0):

Either a **java math function** or a **nested loop** its for your answer. Try yourself its just a mathematical calculation.